# VBA action given data validation list selection

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to get a data validation list selection to perform an action within my spread sheet.

I've got the VBA working to an extent, this code is within the worksheet Sheet1(Sheet1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
  Cancel = True

  With Application
   .EnableEvents = False
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  End With

  ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
  ActiveCell.Select

  With Application
   .EnableEvents = True
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End With
 End If
End Sub
```

In cell A1, I've got a data validation list of options Yes/No.  When I select 'Yes', I want B2 to populate with 'Yes', when I select 'No', I want B2 to be 'No' etc;

It's almost working, but not when I make the selection, but when I select the cell.  e.g. A1 = 'Yes'.  Click away from A1 then click in A1 and B2 becomes 'Yes'.  Change the selection to 'No' and B2 doesn't update to 'No'.

If I click away and click back on A1 again, B2 will change to No.

I'm assuming this is a very subtle mistake, but my VBA knowledge isn't good enough to spot it.  I'm currently doing this a proof of concept before I get on to my more complex spread sheet that needs this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You are using the `SelectionChange` event. Why not use the `Change` event which is triggered by a change in a cell's contents?

Comment: Thanks @SJR, as I say, I don't know much about VBA, I didn't realise that there was a stand alone Change event.  I've made this tweak and all is working as I'd like now.  Many thanks.